# Understanding the behavior of protected members in class

Tags: java, inheritance, package, protected

I am trying to understand the behavior of protected member in a class. I have a class `TopClass` which contains protected integer `pr`.

**Class:**

```
package com.test;

import com.test.anotherpackage.SubClass1;
import com.test.anotherpackage.SubClass2;
import com.test.anotherpackage.SubClass3;

public class TopClass {
    protected int pr;

    void action(TopClass t, SubClass1 s1, SubClass2 s2, SubClass3 s3) {
        t.pr = 3;
        s1.pr = 0;
        s2.pr = 1;
        s3.pr = 1;
    }
}
```

There is another package `com.test.anotherpackage` which has 3 classes `SubClass1`,`SubClass2` and `SubClass3`. Inheritance hierarchy is as follows:

1. `SubClass1 extends TopClass`
2. `SubClass2 extends SubClass1`
3. `SubClass3 extends SubClass2`

**SubClass1**

```
package com.test.anotherpackage;

import com.test.TopClass;

public class SubClass1 extends TopClass {

    void action(TopClass t, SubClass1 s1, SubClass2 s2, SubClass3 s3) {
        t.pr = 0; // Error because not in same package.
        s1.pr = 0; //(1)
        s2.pr = 1; // Does not throw an Exception. Why? (2)
        s3.pr = 1; // (3)
    }
}
```

**SubClass2**

```
package com.test.anotherpackage;

import com.test.TopClass;

public class SubClass2 extends SubClass1 {
    void action(TopClass t, SubClass1 s1, SubClass2 s2, SubClass3 s3) {
        t.pr = 0; // Error because not in same package.
        s1.pr = 0; // Throws Exception, why?  (4)
        s2.pr = 1; //  (5)
        s3.pr = 1; // Does not throw an Exception. Why?(6)
    }
}
```

**SubClass3**

```
package com.test.anotherpackage;

import com.test.TopClass;

public class SubClass3 extends SubClass2 {
    void action(TopClass t, SubClass1 s1, SubClass2 s2, SubClass3 s3) {
        t.pr = 0; 
        s1.pr = 0; // Not Visible (7)
        s2.pr = 1; // Not Visible (8)
        s3.pr = 1; // (9)
    }
}
```

In above code, `(1)`, `(2)`, `(3)`, `(5)`, `(6)` and `(9)` work perfectly without any visibility issues. But `(4)`, `(7)`, `(8)` have visibility issues.

According to [JLS§6.6.2.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.2.1),

> Let C be the class in which a protected member is declared. Access is
>   permitted only within the body of a subclass S of C.
>
> In addition, if Id denotes an instance field or instance method, then:
>
> If the access is by a qualified name Q.Id, where Q is an
>   ExpressionName, then the access is permitted if and only if the type
>   of the expression Q is S or a subclass of S.
>
> If the access is by a field access expression E.Id, where E is a
>   Primary expression, or by a method invocation expression E.Id(. . .),
>   where E is a Primary expression, then the access is permitted if and
>   only if the type of E is S or a subclass of S.

Thing I am trying to understand here is why `if the type of the expression Q is S or a subclass of S` comes into picture. Is there any specific scenario in which this implementation can be beneficial? Any related example will be highly appreciated. I tried looking it on SO, but couldn't find an explanation which could solve my doubt.

Answer (score 0):

The expression you're discussing is also the one responsible for your questions in the code:

`if the type of the expression Q is S or a subclass of S`

`(2)` because the type of the expression `s2` is a subclass of `SubClass1`
`(4)` because the type of the expression `s1` is not a subclass of `SubClass2`
`(5)` because the type of the expression `s3` is a subclass of `SubClass2`

However, I don't know of

> any specific scenario in which this implementation can be beneficial

either.

Comment: Reasons you explained are already covered by JLS§6.6.2.1. I wanted to know why the implementation has that clause. I do not understand the reason behind permitting accessibility via subclass reference in superclass.